# service start mysql error libstdc++.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Tags: mysql, libstdc++

I am having an issue with my MySQL installation and could do with some help

When every I try to start the MySQL service I get the error

```
[valve@Simple-vm2 ~]$ service mysql start
/usr/bin/my_print_defaults: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: wrong    ELF class: ELFCLASS32
Starting MySQL.The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/Simple-vm2.servername.net.pid).                                 [FAILED]
```

(servername hidden)

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: It looks like a 32/64 bit problem. Is your linux 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: @Julian 64-bit CentOS 6.5

Comment: Have a look at https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=2265 and see if you can make sure you have installed 64 bit libstdc++